# tf.contrib.learn API trains faster?

Tags: tensorflow

I am currently experimenting with the tensorflow APIs and need help with the retrain.py for retraining inception.

I am trying out the new tf.contrib.learn APIs and would like to change retrain.py to use the new high level APIs.

However, currently I am facing issues with
1. porting over the Tensorboard logging features in the original script
2. defining the input_fn to return data in minibatches

I tried finding examples online for this and couldn't find any.
May I know if any of you tried doing this before and how did you solve the problems mentioned above?

In addition to this, I would like to know if there are any differences in these 2 ways of computing the accuracy metrics. I'm asking this because I got a 96% accuracy result on the flower_photos sample dataset which is a significant improvement over the original 91% by porting over the model to tf.contrib.learn.

Method 1: Using eval_metric_ops in model_fn function

```
# Calculate accuracy as additional eval metric
eval_metric_ops = {
    "accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(targets, one_hot_classes)
}
```

Method 2: Calculating it manually in the original retrain.py

```
with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
with tf.name_scope('correct_prediction'):
    prediction = tf.argmax(result_tensor, 1)
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(
        prediction, tf.argmax(ground_truth_tensor, 1))
with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
    evaluation_step = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
```

Comment: The method 1 is accumulative while method 2 calculates accuracy only for a batch.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, may I know where did you get this information that method 1 is accumulative?